# Ember: {{link-to}} helper error when in {{each}} helper

Tags: ember.js

The `link-to`helper return the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: each doesn't match link-to - 5:10
```

**The template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="actions">
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="row">    <!--  -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">    <!--  -->
        {{#each action in model}}
          {{link-to 'action' action}}{{action.id}}{{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
        {{outlet}}
      </div>       
    </div>
  </div> 
</script>
```

**The router:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('application', function() {
    this.resource('actions', function() {
      this.resource('action', { path: '/:action_id'});
    });  
});
```

**The route:**

```
App.ActionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('action');
    //return this.modelFor('user').get('actions');
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  },

});
```

I cannot find what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a quite small error. When using a block helper such as `each` or `link-to` you need to invoke them with a # in front, such as you have done with `{{#each}}`. Since you lack that on your starting `link-to`, the parser sees the `{{/link-to}}` and notices that it currently is working with a `each`-block and those doesn't match. Just add a # in front of your starting 'link-to' and it should work fine.

```
{{#each action in model}}
    {{#link-to 'action' action}}{{action.id}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```